# Javascript Webcam Pose Detection - PoseNet Library Issue

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, webcam, tensorflow.js, pose-estimation

I am working on a web app that incorporates camera pose estimation using the PoseNet library. The goal is to record the webcam stream and display the original video frame on one canvas while showing the pose-detected frame on another canvas. However, I am facing an issue where the second canvas displaying the pose-detected frame remains blank.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Webcam Pose Detection</title>
   <!-- Include TensorFlow.js and Posenet library -->
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@3.12.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet@2.2.1/dist/posenet.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- Video element to display webcam stream -->
   <video id="videoElement" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>

   <!-- Container for the canvases -->
   <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <!-- "Original Video Frame" -->
      <div>
         <h3>Original Video Frame</h3>
         <canvas id="canvasElement" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
      </div>

      <!-- "Pose Detected Frame" -->
      <div>
         <h3>Pose Detected Frame</h3>
         <canvas id="canvasElement2" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
      </div>
   </div>

   <script>
      // ... (The rest of the JavaScript code)

      // Function to stop webcam streaming
      function stopCam() {
         const videoElement = document.getElementById('videoElement');
         const stream = videoElement.srcObject;
         const tracks = stream.getTracks();
         tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
      }
   </script>

   <!-- Buttons to start and stop webcam streaming -->
   <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
      <button onclick="openCam()">Start Recording</button>
      <button onclick="stopCam()">Stop Recording</button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help or guidance to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!